# Can I apply factor when running load tests jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load

I have the following scenario:

every 1/2 hour a user send a file to the server

every 5 seconds a user pings the server

do it for 4000 users during 24 hours

my question is, can i do the following and achieve the same results?

every 15 minutes a user send a file to the server

every 2.5 seconds a user pings the server

do it for 2000 users during 24 hours

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and configure it to have 4000 virtual users, loop forever and run for 84600 seconds (24 hours * 60 minutes per hour * 60 seconds per minute)

   [image: JMeter Thread Group for 24 hours]
2. Add a [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to ping the server
3. Add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and configure it to fire 12 times per minute (60 seconds in minute / 5 seconds)

   [image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer]

   Amend `Calculalte throughput based on` dropdown value according to your test scenario (whether each user or any user should ping the server each 5 seconds)
4. Apply the similar configuration for remaining use cases.

Comment: you are not answering my question. what i asked is if the two scenarios are the same from the load perspective. i want to know if i can use less users and less time and achieve the same load.

Comment: They are not the same in terms of keeping 2x more open connections/sessions. Your test must represent real life application usage and JMeter virtual user should map 1-to-1 the real user